# Android Actionbar SearchView

Tags: android, search, android-actionbar, searchview

I want to implement Actionbar SearchView same as QuizUp (attached pictures). My code structure is, one main activity with multiple fragments. Actionbar SearchView is common feature and not related to the any fragment and result will be fetched from remote service.

Need help with some sample codes. Pls check attached images to get clear idea about my requirement.

Thanks

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

[image: Step 1]

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

[image: Step 2]

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

[image: Step 3]

Answer (score 0):

I think it is kinda impossible with simple SearchView.

You can do it with transparent activity.

For example, you have menuItem with search button, when user click it, application open new activity with transparent background and searchView

[How to create transparent activity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2700683/4252851)